# How can I set up SQLite to handle Multi-threaded persistence in C on Android JNI

Tags: android, c, sqlite, java-native-interface

How can I set it up SQLite so that it does multi-threaded persistence in **Android** **`JNI`** in **`C`**?

This is how I set up SQLite, but the SQLite database is getting locked sometimes when doing multiple persistence :

For persistence :

**DB initialization:**

```
void initMyDb(char *dirPath) {
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    const char *myDbName = "/my_lite.db";

    char *myDbPath;
    myDbPath = malloc(strlen(dirPath) + 1 + 4); /* make space for the new string (should check the return value ...) */
    strcpy(myDbPath, dirPath); /* copy name into the new var */
    strcat(myDbPath, myDbName); /* add the extension */

    rc = sqlite3_open(dirPath, &db);

    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }
}  

sqlite3 *myDb() {
    sqlite3 *db;
    int rc;

    rc = sqlite3_open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/my_lite.db", &db);

    if (rc) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open database: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        return (0);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
    }

    return db;
}
```

**Create:**

```
long myPersRelationshipObject(MyEntityRelationship *myEntityRelationship) {
    long myReturnVal = -1;

    sqlite3 *db = myDb();

    if (!db)
        return -1;

    int _myResolveStatus = myEntityRelationship->_myResolveStatus;

    int rc;
    char *szSQL;
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    szSQL = "INSERT INTO MY_ENTITY_RELATIONSHIPS_TABLE (" \
    "MY_RESOLVE_STATUS, " 
    "values (?)";

    rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, szSQL, strlen(szSQL), &stmt, 0);

    if (rc == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, _myResolveStatus);
    }

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: myPersRelationshipObject %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));

        myReturnVal = -1;
    } else {
        sqlite3_step(stmt);
        myReturnVal = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return myReturnVal;
}
```

**Read:**

```
long getRevRelationshipTypeValueId(long revEntitySubjectGUID, long revEntityTargetGuid) {
    long revRelTypeValId = -1;

    sqlite3 *db = revDb();

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    char *sql = "SELECT "
    "REV_RELATIONSHIP_TYPE_VALUE_ID "
    "FROM REV_ENTITY_RELATIONSHIPS_TABLE "
    "WHERE REV_SUBJECT_GUID = ? AND REV_TARGET_GUID = ?";

    int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, revEntitySubjectGUID);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 2, revEntityTargetGuid);

    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: getRevRelationshipTypeValueId %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
    }

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        revRelTypeValId = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 0);

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    sqlite3_close(db);

    return revRelTypeValId;
}
```

Comment: Did you try [Using SQLite In Multi-Threaded Applications](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thank you for the reply. I looked at that, but it does not really say much about the setup.

Comment: *"I looked at that, but it does not really say much about the setup."* Define setup, what do you mean with that? i assume you mean [How To Compile SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html)